# Intersection of cut locus and conjugate locus

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Weinstein, in the article **[The Cut Locus and Conjugate Locus of a Riemannian Manifold](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970592?origin=crossref)** proved that for a compact differentiable manifold $M$, which is not homeomorphic to $S^2$, there always exists a Riemannian metric on $M$ and a point $p\in M$ whose conjugate locus and cut locus are disjoint.

I was thinking if the following has a positive answer:

> Let $M$ be a Finsler manifold which is not Riemannian. Then is it true that for every $p\in M$, the intersection of cut and conjugate locus is non-empty?

Comment: What did you try to disprove your conjecture?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I do not have much evidence for this. I only have a set of examples to support the conjecture. Weinstein's proof does not follow directly, so that is why I was wondering.

Comment: Try torus. Can you think of a metric which has empty conjugate locus?

Comment: If we give a flat metric, then the conjugate locus is empty. But this is the case even in the Riemannian metric as well. What if we impose the condition that the conjugate locus is non-empty? Because for any flat metric conjugate locus is empty.

Comment: Well, try to find a Finsler/nonRiemannian metric on the torus with empty conjugate locus. As for metrics with nonempty conjugate locus, it would be a different question (but the answer surely the same).